# Forcing hibernate to release connection on session Spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jdbc, transactions

I am using Spring MVC 3 and Hibernate 3.6, I use xml configured transaction management,
my code works greate but my JDBC are not being released although it says it does.

I checked it with JProfiler and it says the connection is open.

this is my spring-config code

```
<bean id="ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parse_web?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="miles106" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="50000"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/mubasher/parsewebpage/entities/Changes.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/mubasher/parsewebpage/entities/Owners.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/mubasher/parsewebpage/entities/Ownerships.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/mubasher/parsewebpage/entities/TargetCompanies.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/mubasher/parsewebpage/entities/TempData.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/mubasher/parsewebpage/entities/Exceptions.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

and this is my debug code

> DEBUG [myExec-2] (JDBCTransaction.java:223) - re-enabling autocommit
>   DEBUG [myExec-2] (JDBCTransaction.java:143) - committed JDBC Connection
>   DEBUG [myExec-2] (ConnectionManager.java:427) - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
>   DEBUG [myExec-2] (ConnectionManager.java:464) - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
>   DEBUG [myExec-2] (HibernateTransactionManager.java:734) - Closing Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@52ab7af2] after transaction
>   DEBUG [myExec-2] (SessionFactoryUtils.java:789) - Closing Hibernate Session

but in JProfiler i can see that the connection is still open as you see

[image]

this is realy causing me problems, my application is doing massive database work, so I need the connection to close as soon as the work is done, should I use maxIdle ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connections are not closed, they are reused. This is the whole purpose of **commons-dbcp**, which stands for **Database Connection Pool**.

Establishing a new connection is usually an expensive operation. So what DBCP is doing is that instead of closing connection, it leaves it open and returns it to the connection pool for another use.

If you want your database connections to get closed and re-opened with each request, then you need to use a **different data source** (e.g. `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource`).

---

**UPDATE 1:** Also note, that in your example you are setting maximum number of parallel connections (`maxActive`) to be 50000. That is some extreme number (default is **8!!!**), which IMO can cause a lot of problems.

**UPDATE 2:** Using `maxIdle` is a good idea if you don't wan't to get rid of the pool. But that will not save you from *"having non-closed connections"*. If you are thinking about setting `maxIdle=0`, then drop the pool completely.

**UPDAET 3:** I just need to stress out this one again - **If you need 50000 parallel connections, then there is really something wrong with your code.**

Comment: Thanks Pavel, the problem is when I leave my application like that, and the rerun after say one day, the connection pool throws an error that some request has been sent to the source from yesterday and it has not returned, and when I use tomcat check leaks it says that it could be a leak

Comment: Ad. connection problem - if you have connection pool, you need to make sure that the connection is still alive (e.g. database machine might be rebooted during the time the connection was sitting idle in the pool) when you are re-using it. This is why `BasicDataSource` supports `validationQuery`. When a connection is going to be re-used, the pool calls this query to verify that the connection is alive. We are using `SELECT 1` (PostgreSQL specific, might not work in MySQL).

Comment: Ad. memory leak - this is very annoying Tomcat validation message. I think you can ignore this one.

Comment: Thanks Paven you were right i double checked my code and connections and found the bug, I don't need this stupid solultion any more, could you lease check my other question did not fix it till now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936844/hibernate-transactions-does-not-start-until-the-mvc-request-is-done